# Move Div not only while hovering but when another div reach the top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can someone tell me why my code isn't working?

```js
var distance = $('#introSection').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
    document.getElementById("hoveredLink").style.left = document.getElementById("introNav").target.offsetLeft + "px";
    document.getElementById("hoveredLink").style.left = document.getElementById("introNav").target.offsetWidth + "px"; 
    }
});
```

I want the "hoveredLink" element to scroll to the menu element "introNav" if the "introSection" reaches the very top of the window :( is not working yet though

Comment: your snippet is not functional currently - can you add the HTML content and also refer jquery as well ? that way other will be able to debug your issue better.

Comment: that's the problem @abhijat_saxena that I'm making my website with webflow, I can't extract the entire code that easy. But I'm mentioning all the divs id's involved.

Being: introSection the section that reaches the top, hoveredLink the element that moves to the navbar location (related to the section) and the IntroNav the id for that menu element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it this way it will work.

```js
 var distance = 10;
$('body').scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ( scroll >= distance ) {
    console.log("i am working!");
    }
});
```